# What to look for after Cassandra repair

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, repair, nodetool

We have issues currently with our cluster and it has been recommended that we don't run OpsCenter until we add some more nodes/scale up our current environment.  That said, we obviously can't run the continuous repair with OpsCenter down and thus have to runs repairs once per week.

As such, I have them scheduled to run as cron jobs, I just was wondering today what do I look for in the logs to ensure that the jobs completed successfully?  I "think" they finished fine, and nothing is currently running, but I was just wondered what the message/entry in the log file should be for a successfully completed repair.

Answer (score 2):

Look for "anti entropy" and "validation" errors in the system.log.

There are some scripts on github for continuous range repairs if your large manual jobs start failing.

[Here's an example](https://github.com/mstump/cassandra_range_repair)

OpsCenter repair is great, hopefully you'll be back on OpsC with more nodes. Also consider a side cluster for opsc.
[OpsCenter on a different cluster](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/5.1/opsc/configure/opscStoringCollectionDataDifferentCluster_t.html)